# How to set hardcoded select value to value instead of null in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, data-binding

I am trying to hardcode a default value for a `<select>` in AngularJS that set the value to `0` instead of `null`.

This without having to push an *"None selected"* object to the actual item collection that I bind towards or having the "save function" sanitize the object.

What is the most elegant way to implement a hardcoded default option with a proper value instead of null?

---

[Fiddle explaining the problem](http://jsfiddle.net/r4qdj/1/)

If you select an parent and then select the default value you will get a null parentId instead of 0.

Comment: I am not sure there is a clean solution. AngularJS tend to discriminate against `<option>` in favor of `ng-option`. I concat the array with the default value before display personally.

Comment: Well, you gave me an idea. I could use a prepend filter that prepends a default object which at least keep me from modifying the collection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this by using a prepend filter which takes the hardcoded select value as an argument.

#### Filter:

```
myApp.filter('prepend', function() {
    return function(input, prependObj) {
        var out = [prependObj];
        out = out.concat(input);
        return out;
    };
});
```

#### Sample usage:

```
<select ng-model="editItem.parentId" ng-options="i.id as i.title for i in (items | prepend:{id:0, title:'No parent'})">
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r4qdj/3/)